# p4v does not show the complete list of checked out files

Tags: perforce, p4v

If I checkout 4000 files in p4v it does not show me the complete list of files in the default changelist. It just says 4000 files checked out. Is there any way that I can view the complete list of 4000 files?

Answer (score 35):

Open the preferences dialog via the Edit->Preferences menu.  Click on "Server Data" and you'll see a setting labeled "Maximum number of files displayed per changelist*:"  Raise that to 4000+ and you should see all those files.

[image: P4 Server Data prefs]

Comment: In v2013.3 this is under `Edit -> Preferences -> Server Data`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible in p4v. In a command line shell however you could use

```
p4 opened -c default > list_of_files
```

and examine the list with your favorite viewer.

To mass change filetypes from the command line you can use:

```
p4 edit -t text <filepattern>
```

or

```
p4 -x list_of_file_to_change edit -t text
```

To change all files of the default change list to filetype text you would use (UNIX/Linux)

```
p4 opened -c default | sed 's/#.*//' | p4 -x - reopen -t text
```

Comment: Could you let me know if there is a command line way to change all the filetypes in default changelist from unicode to text?

Answer (score 0):

You can always capture output of `p4 fstat ...` and find the status of the files you are interested in. Or, better yet, use `p4 fstat` with the relative path to your files. Do you really want to manually go through the huge file list when you have tools do filter them for you?

Comment: I just wanted to change the filetypes from unicode to text for all the files and that is why I wanted to checkout all of them, and then change the file types to text for all of them, and then submit. Could you please let me know if I can do this in command line?

Comment: `p4 files -a //... | findstr "\(.*unicode\)"` is your starting point. More details at perforce knowledge base (http://kb.perforce.com/article/1170/unicode-file-type-handling-changes-in-20092)   Use `...` instead of `//...` if you want to limit your query to the current directory and below. Use `.../*.h` to limit it to .h files, et cetera